# Importing and Displaying Facebook Events on the MAP: Xcode, iOS, Mapkit.framework

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, mapkit

I am developing my iOS app, I am able to get the events through FB GRAPH API 
(Thanks to this : https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos).

Now I need to show them inside the MAP, any suggestion??
I am using MAPKIT framework and iOS 7 as target.

Thank you,
F.

ps: both swift or Objective C solutions would be ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to get the latitude and longitude of the Facebook events, then add them to an `MKMapView` with the `MKAnnotation` API.

Comment: Thank you, I am now able to get the latitude and longitude thanks to the field attribute "venue". I will check MKAnnotation API then.